# Why can't select label with document.forms?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is it possible to get label or div with document.forms ?

If yes. how ?

If not. Why ?

When I try it gives "undefined";

Example Code:

```
<form name="form1">
    <div id="div1">
        <label id="label1" for="uname">Username: </label> 
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" >
        <button id="button1" onclick="func1()" >Okay!</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
var form=document.forms['form1'];

function func1() {
    event.preventDefault(); // -
    console.log(form["uname"]); // gives input element
    console.log(form["button1"]); // gives buttonn element
    console.log(form["label1"]); // undefined
    console.log(form["div1"]); // undefined
    
    // I can get them like :
    console.log(form["uname"].previousElementSibling); // gives label element
    console.log(form["uname"].parentElement); // gives div element
    // ...etc
    // but, the questions is why I can't with document.forms
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select div because div are not part of form element. [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)

```js
var form=document.forms['form1'];

function func1() {
    event.preventDefault(); // -
    console.log(form["uname"]); // gives input element
    console.log(form["button1"]); // gives buttonn element
    console.log( form["uname"].labels[0] )
    console.log(form["div1"]); // cant select div, because div are not form element
    
    // I can get them like :
    console.log(form["uname"].previousElementSibling); // gives label element
    console.log(form["uname"].parentElement); // gives div element
    // ...etc
    // but, the questions is why I can't with document.forms
}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
    <div id="div1">
        <label id="label1" for="uname">Username: </label> 
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" >
        <button id="button1" onclick="func1()" >Okay!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Content elements contained within a  form have no relevance to the form being processed for being valid or submitted so there is no reason those content elements would need to be part of the form object.

You can however use `form.querySelector()` to target them

```js
const form = document.forms.form1,
 label = form.querySelector('#label1');
 
 console.log('Label text = ', label.textContent)
```

```html
<form name="form1">
    <div id="div1">
        <label id="label1" for="uname">Username: </label> 
        <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" >
        <button id="button1" onclick="func1()" >Okay!</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `form[elementId]` returns the input element with that id. But that doesn't work as it only works for input elements. What you could do instead is `form.elements`, this is a [HTMLColection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which you could use with ids to get elements. `form.elements[elementId]`.

Although that works, I would recomend you use `document.getElementById`. This way you don't need to understand old html/js jank. You would use it like this:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("uname")); // gives input element
console.log(document.getElementById("button1")); // gives button1 element
console.log(document.getElementById("label1")); // gives label element
console.log(document.getElementById("div1")); // gives div element
```